# javax validation not validating complex object attributes

Tags: java, validation

I am trying to validate a class using javax.validation.Validator. Below is what I am doing.

```
final Set<ConstraintViolation<PaymentDetailsForm>> set = validator.validate(accountPaymentDetailsForm);
```

My paymentDetailForm looks like this

```
public class PaymentDetailsForm
{
    private String paymentId;
    private String cardTypeCode;
    private Boolean newBillingAddress;
    private AddressForm billingAddress;
    private String securityCode;
```

When I am submitting the form it is validating the paymentId,cardTypeCode, etc. But it is not validating the billingAddress form which is inside PaymentDetailsForm.

Do I need to give any anotation on getBillingAddress() method?

Comment: Can you annotate billingAddress with @valid

Comment: yup that worked ...awesome

Comment: close this question if you found the answer

Comment: @SujitChaitanya - can you add your comment as an answer so i can close the question.